# Unable to find generated app .apk in Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I am developing an android app project and I am able to directly load it on my android phone. But I am unable to find the .apk file corresponding to the app. I have already checked out a few stackoverflow pages for how to resolve this, but I am unable to do so.

I do not have a **bin** folder at all anywhere within my project. The only .apks I am able to find within the folders are the **app-debug.apk** and related ones.

How do I force generate the apk when I run the project within **Android Studio**? Such problems do not exist in **Eclipse**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio puts resulting apks in the `<your-project-name>/<your-app-name>/build/outputs/apk/` directory. Look here.

Comment: There there is an app_debug.apk . Is that the one which I should use?

Comment: @SoulRayder well, it depends on what you're looking for. the `app-debug.apk` is the debug version of your application which can be used for testing. if you need the release version which can be published on Play Market, you need to select the `release` build variant and build the project. the `app_release.apk` will be your desired file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to debug the application you can use the app-debug. Otherwise go up to build and press generate signed apk and choose release (if you want it as the final app) or debug for debugging.

Comment: So the app-debug.apk serves as the unsigned apk for all intents and purposes? What is the difference between this and the final unsigned apk you can easily find when using eclipse project?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Eclipse since I haven't used it in a while. If you want to create the app that will be distributed you choose Release under generate signed apk